# Why upstart won't start the process sometimes?

Tags: 14.04, upstart

I am using upstart feature of Ubuntu to restart my program whenever any machine gets rebooted under any circumstance. What I am seeing is **sometimes** machine gets rebooted but my progam doesn't get started up again and I have to login to the box and start manually.

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /nwotr
respawn

post-stop script
  sleep 30
end script

limit core unlimited unlimited
limit nofile 8092 8092
setuid golds
exec python executeproc.py
```

These boxes are VM's residing under a hypervisor. I am not sure whether there is anything I need to modify for `runlevel` to make this work?

Is there any settings which I can add by which upstart will start my process always whenever machine gets rebooted? I can reproduce this easily I guess so if there is any way by which we can debug this out, let me know as well.